# intellisense on extension of Url.Content

Tags: c#, razor, resharper, intellisense

When using MVC Razor you often write @Url.Content("~/images/someimage.png") and you get intellisense on that string - it somehow knows that it's a path.

I created an extension method for Url.Content() but it doesn't get intellisense when typing the path parameter.

Does anyone know if there is some kind of attribute you can put on parameters, or is there a better way (an override?) I can cut in and change the default Url.Content's behaviour?

```
    public static string ContentExtended(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string contentPath)
    {
        string result = urlHelper.Content(contentPath);

        // do stuff here to remove application folder name on godaddy hosting

        return result;
    }
```

**EDIT: I use resharper, and just realised this might be a resharper-specific feature that regular VS users don't actually have. I disabled Resharper intellisense, and just had the regular VS intellisense on, and the path specific auto-complete didn't work. So this is a resharper feature, not a programming problem**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt, it's really ReSharper's feature.
You need to mark contentPath parameter with PathReferenceAttribute attribute.
You can copy it's implementation to your project from ReSharper → Options → Code Inspection → Code Annotations.

Comment: Fantastic! This was what I needed, I'm going to recap your instructions, hopefully makes it a bit clearer to anyone else who comes along:
Go to: ReSharper → Options → Code Inspection → Code Annotations → Click "Copy default implementation to clipboard" and create a new class file and paste the results into it.
Then add attribute to parameter like this: public static string ContentExtended(this UrlHelper urlHelper, [JetBrains.Annotations.PathReference] string contentPath)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to provide XML documentation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Lorem ipsum...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="urlHelper">The helper to provide content to</param>
/// <param name="contentPath">The path to the content</param>
```

This isn't just for extension methods - it's how you provide documentation (picked up by IntelliSense) for everything.

If you're talking about something more than that, in terms of IntelliSense suggesting possible values, *that* may be an attribute...

Comment: I don't mean just intellisense help on what the paramater is for, I mean specific "path" intellisense. i.e. using the example above as soon as you type ~/im when using Url.Content (and push CTRL+SPACE if you need to) it will finish typing "~/images/". It knows it's a path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC to have static content intellsense.